# PostgreSQL accessing multiple elements from array by using positional array

Tags: arrays, postgresql

I'd like to know whether it is possible in PostgreSQL to output an array from multiple elements of an array by using another array indicating a series of positions for elements.

To be precise:

```
array1 = [1,2,1]        
array_positions(array1,'1') = {1,3}
array2 = ['hello', 'bye', 'hello']
```

Desired result:

```
array2[array_positions(array1,'1')] = {'hello', 'hello'}
```

I receive `ERROR:  array subscript must have type integer`
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The missing part is a function/operator that returns array elements from specified positions (I really surprised that it is absent in the release, hope it will be fixed). Lets create them:

```
create or replace function array_from_positions(anyarray, int[]) returns anyarray
  immutable language sql 
as $$
  select array_agg(a.x order by b.i)
  from
    unnest($1) with ordinality as a(x,i)
      right join unnest($2) with ordinality as b(x,i) on (a.i=b.x)
$$;
```

Test:

```
select
  array_from_positions('{a,b,c,d}'::text[], '{2,1,10}'),
  array_from_positions('{1,2,3,4}'::int[], '{2,1,10}');
```

```
┌──────────────────────┬──────────────────────┐
│ array_from_positions │ array_from_positions │
├──────────────────────┼──────────────────────┤
│ {b,a,NULL}           │ {2,1,NULL}           │
└──────────────────────┴──────────────────────┘
```

```
create operator ## (
  procedure = array_from_positions,
  leftarg = anyarray,
  rightarg = int[] );
```

Test:

```
select
  '{a,b,c,d}'::text[] ## '{2,1,10}',
  '{1,2,3,4}'::int[] ## '{2,1,10}';
```

```
┌────────────┬────────────┐
│  ?column?  │  ?column?  │
├────────────┼────────────┤
│ {b,a,NULL} │ {2,1,NULL} │
└────────────┴────────────┘
```

And final test for your example:

```
with your_table(array1,array2) as (values
  ('{1,2,1}'::int[], '{hello,bye,hello}'::text[]))
select array2 ## array_positions(array1, 1) from your_table;
```

```
┌───────────────┐
│   ?column?    │
├───────────────┤
│ {hello,hello} │
└───────────────┘
```

Answer (score 2):

This may or may not be too complicated to be useful, but it does prove it's possible:

```
SELECT vals.*
FROM (
  VALUES(array['hello', 'bye', 'hello'])
) AS t (arr)
JOIN lateral unnest(t.arr) WITH ORDINALITY AS vals(element, idx) ON TRUE
WHERE vals.idx = ANY(array_positions(array[1,2,1], 1));
```

Comment: Preferably my input array (containing 'hello') comes from a different table (instead of raw values), and my output mode would also be an array

Comment: `VALUES` in a `FROM` clause just allows you to create a fake "table" when you need it for an example. You can use a real table.